# Holding the bride's hand when giving her the ring

Tags: halacha, women, wedding, hands-fingers

In art I see that it was done [example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Isra%C3%ABls-A_Jewish_Wedding-1903.jpg)
From [hukai noshim CH 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uv6q.jpg) I see that it is required (at least lehat'hila)

My summery of this subject in that chapter

> He brings it twice once regarding when doing kedushin on money and once when doing kedushin with a ring, he says: to hold her right hand in his left hand and hold the money/ring in his right hand
>   By money: he should say hari at mekudeshes li... then but the money in her right hand and let go and then say kdas moshe visrael.
>   By ring: he should but the ring on her finger and say the whole saying, and then let go when he lets go she acquires it

I guess the reason might be that even when the groom is holding the ring since it is one her finger (she can take her finger away with the ring) it already belongs to her before he finished saying mekudeshes li bze, but if he hold her hand she does not aquier it yet

On many weddings i do not see it done

Why is it not done?
Was it always like this? (If not when and why did it start?)
Are there groups of Jews that do it? If yes which?

Comment: The Sefer Maharil records (Ed. Spitzer, pg. 464) that it was the custom for the Chatan to take the hand of the Kallah on the day of their wedding: הלך הרב והחשובים והיו מוליכין את החתן לקראת הכלה. והחתן תופש אותה בידו ובחיבורן יחד זורקין כל העם על גבי ראשן חטין ואומרים פרו ורבו ג"פ. והולכין יחד עד אצל פתח בה"כ ויושבין שם מעט ומוליכין הכלה לביתה. See more here: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2016/06/engaged-couples-and-more.html

Comment: @Chaim was that not regarding after the kidduchin?

Comment: @hazoriz Nope, he writes this was done first thing in the morning. The beginning of the paragraph goes: בעלות השחר ביום הששי היה קורא השמש לבא לבה"כ, ומביאים הכלה וחברותיה. וכאשר תבא עד פתח חצר בה"כ הלך הרב...

Comment: @Chaim how do you know they did not make the kedushin at an earlier date?

Comment: @hazoriz I am merely echoing the words of Marc B. Shapiro who authored that article. He also quotes R. Israel David Margulies (19th century) who understood this as taking place prior to Kiddushin, and who suggests that there was no הרהור since the brides were generally very young. I suggest reading the complete section from Sefer Maharil itself for contextual clarity.

Comment: @Chaim from here it seems after kedushin and before nisuin sheva brochois. Third paragraph http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_27989_29.pdf . What you are saying is that after kidduchin the kala is still forbidden to the hasan as a nidda is (so there is a problem of nida) until the hupa 7brochois

Comment: @Chaim this is more clear http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21749_76.pdf and http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21749_77.pdf

Comment: @Chaim in paragraph 11 it seems that you are right

Comment: Beginning of the next page is regarding (my question) touching when putting on the ring http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21749_78.pdf

Comment: My theory for an answer is that originally he did hold the bride's hand but latter the niddois were embarrassed so they started putting on the ring without touching even when she was not a nidda

Comment: (I'll post it as an answer so you can downvote without commenting instead of just deleting.) There is 0 halachic basis fornot touching an unmarried, non-niddah woman. My guess is that there is an unfortunate human tendency toward what people feel is intuitively "frum", rather than toward actual knowledge of halacha. touching girls is seen as bad, and people don't know that, in this particular situation there is nothing wrong with it at all, so they avoid contact. not embarrassing niddos doesn't really jive nowadays because medications for controlling the menstrual cycle basically always used.